# SelectQuery with ' WHEN,THEN,ELSE,END' condition?

Tags: java, sql, database, transactions, jooq

I have an issue with selectquery condition, I know the selectquery condition is wrong. So anyone can help me how to set this condition here.

```
caseInfoList = new GroupModel<CaseInfoDataNew>();
Transaction transaction = Transaction.current();
SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery();
selectQuery.addSelect("CASE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup WHEN null THEN ValidInfo.InfoGroup ELSE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup END InfoGroup");
```

> But i want to change string argument  into field.how it can possible .

**Error:-**
The method addSelect(Field...) in the type SelectQuery is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: What is your goal with this query?

Comment: i want to change this condition with select query selectQuery.addSelect("CASE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup WHEN null THEN ValidInfo.InfoGroup ELSE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup END InfoGroup");

Comment: You aren't using the word "select" anywhere in your select query. Think about that for a second.

Comment: WHEN IS NULL, and not WHEN NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't tried jOOQ's [`CASE` expression support](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/) yet? The solution would resemble this:

```
selectQuery.addSelect(
    DSL.decode().value(ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup)
                .when(DSL.val(null), ValidInfo.InfoGroup)
                .otherwise(ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup)
                .as("InfoGroup")
);
```

However, given your actual `CASE` expression, you're probably better off using [`nvl`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#nvl%28org.jooq.Field,%20org.jooq.Field%29):

```
selectQuery.addSelect(
    DSL.nvl(ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup, ValidInfo.InfoGroup).as("InfoGroup")
);
```

Comment: The method val(null) is undefined for the type CivilFolderInfoEditViewModel

Comment: I updated my answer. `val()` is from [DSL](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(T)). I suggest you read through the [manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/). It contains a lot of essential information that you will need for further work with jOOQ

Comment: nic answer @Lukas Eder

Answer (score 0):

to check null `is Null` should be used

```
... CASE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup WHEN null THEN ....
```

Comment: John, that SQL expression you're suggesting [is wrong](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22355). The [correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22354) way to express the `WHEN` clause is by writing simply `NULL`, not `IS NULL`

Comment: ok i got it, thanks for suggesting. i will correct same in answer.

Comment: You might as well delete it in its current form ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
selectQuery.addSelect("CASE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup WHEN Is NULL
THEN ValidInfo.InfoGroup ELSE ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup END InfoGroup");
```